# How to keep previous FCM notification after reopening the App?

Tags: android, firebase

I Apply FCM to my Android App to receive notification successfully.
But when I close and reopen the App, previous notification disappear ? How to keep them ?

Answer (score 0):

```
       NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notify=new Notification.Builder
           (getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle(tittle).setContentText(body).
           setContentTitle(subject).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc).build();

           notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
           notif.notify(0, notify);
```

Add flag while creating notification

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way is to save them locally e.g. in preferences file or database
And on restart show them as local notifications
There will be no difference for user
You also can customize the time of appearing as in the past

```
notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeInMillis() - 60_000)
```